# Store Videos Files and Access Them Via Rest API?

Tags: video, mobile, storage

I am trying to build a dancing learning app, its a mobile app for a dancing school, the app should display list of videos and the user can watch the videos from the app, would you please suggest a cloud storage for the videos or where should I store the videos so I can display them in the app, youtube is not my option here, I want to make an advance video player.
thank you so much.

Comment: You cannot ask for product recommends. This is not an advertising platform. Ask here when your code is giving issues. Anyways consider this... So your dance app only shows videos when there is a wi-fi signal around? What's wrong with storing video files on your app's related website (buy web space or use dance school server, store files there, load them from app)? Did you consider compressing the video files and bundling them as data assets with your app, meaning later that your app on loading will unzip the required video and play (no internet needed)?

Comment: Research for [file host direct link](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=file+host+direct+link). These keywords will help you. Best thing is to actually make a test app that loads a video and test loading files from your selected host.